# Instance of client implementation of abstract class in library code

Tags: java, class

I'm writing some kind of library. I have an abstract class there. Client-code needs to extend it to use some methods. May happens that user quits application and after he restarts it I need to restore reference to his concrette class. My idea was to save canonical name of user's class and then just make `newInstance()` for it. However for some reason it can't create the instance. I've made a test:

```
void foo(AbstractClass a) {
    String classname = a.getClass().getCanonicalName();
    System.out.println(classname); //Output: "com.test.clientcode.Main.ConcretteClass"
    a = null; // here I lost my reference to ConcretteClass for example, so all I have is a classname
    Class.forName(classname).newInstance(); //Throws exception: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: `com.test.clientcode.Main.ConcretteClass"
}
```

It's a method within library code. For argument `a` I give it an instance of concrette user class.

UPDATE: to make things easier: in my library I have a method like above, argument `a` is a reference to client's ConcretteClass as we see in the output of 2nd line. Then I lose my reference. How can I make a new instance of ConcretteClass if the only thing I know is ConcretteClass' canonical name?

Comment: `May happens that user quits application and after he restarts it I need to restore reference to his concrette class.` I didn't get it. in your code you didn't keep the reference, you are trying to create a new instance.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, at first I have a reference to some instance of ConcretteClass and keep it for example in static variable of abstract class type. But after restart that static variable becomes null so I need to renew it with new instance of ConcreteClass

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work.

If you want to "restore" the instance you should do in other way instead of simply newInstance. this is one thing. I don't know your concrete requirement, so I cannot answer further on the "restore" part.

I said your approach won't work, because you said your are writing a "library", so I guess client code will import your class, that is, your abstract class is in client codes's classpath. however, the client class won't be in your classpath. that's why you got the classnotfound Ex.

same as if I extend a class from guava for example, how come in guava codes, it knows my class and create an instance of my class?

Comment: Ok, thank you, I got it. My problem: I need to save reference to client's concrette method implementation after application restart. So I could reuse this method without asking client for it everytime. May be there's some other approach to solve it?

Comment: I feel you may have some problem in your design. (not sure). usually, a library should know nothing about client's type. If something related to client concrete needs to be done, it should be done in client's codes. not in library. think about how apache-common, guava, spring, hibernate....even JDK itself worked.

Comment: @Kent disagree. Struts is a library which is used within our projects, but can instantiate `Action`s and `ActionForm`s we define in struts-config xml files, the same is about Spring (using XML), Hibernate (which instantiates entities) and almost all Java frameworks. That's what reflection is for.